# cPanel backup schedule for blocks of sites at different times on different days

Tags: backup, hosting, cpanel, whm

How can I schedule cPanel to backup blocks of websites and store the backups on dropbox at different times during the week. My server is backing up everything all at once then sending them offsite. The problem is the server runs out of disk space because so much data is being backed up at one time.  It would be best to say sites 1-50 get backed up and sent out on Monday night (backups get deleted off server once transferred offsite) then sites 51-100 would get backed up Tuesday night.

Is this possible to do or is there a plugin or service that has the ability to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do it with the cPanel backup system. If you have root access of your server then You will have to setup some custom backup scripts with the rsync commands.